# Can't disable editing on table after deleting a row

Tags: swift, uitableview

In my table view, after I delete a record, I want it to disable editing if the last record was deleted, but even after calling `setEditing` the state doesn't change.  Here's a simplified example that still shows the behavior:

```
class TestViewController: UITableViewController {
    var items = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(add)),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Remove", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(remove))
        ]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        if self.items.count == 0 {
            // This is getting executed, but not changing the table's state
            self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc func add () {
        self.items.append("foo")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @objc func remove () {
        self.tableView.setEditing(!self.tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Clicking the "Remove" button toggles editing on and off without any problems, but if I delete the last one and then add a new one, it still shows up in editing mode.  I tried stepping through the code, and it's definitely hitting the correct line, but even after executing it `tableView.isEditing` is still true. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Interesting... I just confirmed its not working. It could be bug on Apple side. I don't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code, as per Hikaru Watanabe's comment , it is not working.
So i have made change in **commit editingstyle** method and it is working fine, 
please check below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
          if self.items.count == 0 {
             // This is getting executed, but not changing the table's state
             self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
        }
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

**Updated After John's Comment -**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        if self.items.count == 0 {
            // This is getting executed, but not changing the table's state
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
        }else{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's really odd that it works that way.  I'd prefer a solution that works with `reloadData` (my real code involves a database call which potentially returns different data, so I still have to use `reloadData` when the count isn't 0),  but I'm starting to suspect it might not be possible.

Comment: check updated answer - it works fine with reload data too. You just need to use deleteRowsAtIndexPath for last row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return editingEnable
}
```

Just set true or false this variable "editingEnable" on your condition.